# How can I get AppleScript to always place content in the correct field in Messages

Tags: applescript

I have an AppleScript script that works flawlessly *most* of the time. The script is intended to execute from within FileMaker, taking information from it and texting a message to a phone number. Between 10 and 20% of the time, however, after entering the phone number, it enters the content there as well instead of placing it in the message field.

Here's the full AppleScript:

```
set _delay to 1

set _phone_number to repetition 1 of cell "APPLESCRIPT_PIPE" of layout "DEV"
set the clipboard to _phone_number

set _msg to repetition 2 of cell "APPLESCRIPT_PIPE" of layout "DEV"

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Messages"
        set frontmost to true
        keystroke "n" using {command down}
        delay _delay

        keystroke "v" using {command down}
        delay _delay

        keystroke return
        delay _delay

        set _line_count to count of paragraphs of _msg
        repeat with _line_number from 1 to _line_count
            set _line to paragraph _line_number of _msg
            if _line_number = _line_count then
                keystroke _line
                delay _delay

            else if length of _line = 0 then
                keystroke return using {option down}

            else
                keystroke _line
                keystroke return using {option down}

            end if
        end repeat

        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use a delay to reduce the likelihood of the bug, but it hasn't worked. I started with a delay of .25 seconds, then .5, and now 1, but it's still happening.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `keystroke`, I used [UI Browser](http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/) to figure out the path to the content field in Messages, then replaced the entire loop with this:

```
set value of text area 1 of scroll area 4 ¬
    of splitter group 1 of window "Messages" to _msg
```

Comment: **UI Browser** is nice, however for $55.00 US I'd rather save the money and get the _code_ using **Automator**. For example, just record clicking into the _text area_ in **Messages**, stop recording, and drag and drop the **Click the text area.** _event_ outside of the **Watch Me Do** _action_ to see the **UI Scripting** _code_ behind the _event_.

Comment: I have to admit, I've been automating macOS since System 7 days, so my go-to tech for it is AppleScript. I'm not nearly as familiar with Automator. Truth is, I didn't even think of it. But then again, I'm not sure what would be required to launch an Automator macro from FileMaker, the app containing the AppleScript.

Comment: I didn't mention Automator for use in what your are doing with Messages per se, but just to get the UI Scripting code that you used UI Browser for. In other words, doing as I mention in my first comment you can get `text area 1 of scroll area 4 of splitter group 1 of window "Messages" of application process "Messages"` which of course can be used to then: `set value of text area 1 of scroll area 4 of splitter group 1 of window "Messages" to _msg`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution will work a little better for you instead of involving system events...

```
set theMessage to "Whatever Text To Send"
set thePhoneNumber to "555-555-5555" -- Any Phone Number INCLUDE THE QUOTE MARKS
--               * Other Acceptable Phone Number Formats *
-- ("1(555)555-5555","(555)555-5555", "5555555555", "15555555555")

tell application "Messages"
    launch
    delay 5 -- Gives Messages Time To Open (May Need To Adjust)
    send theMessage to buddy thePhoneNumber of service "SMS"
end tell
```

If the above solution does not work for you, you can set the values directly rather than using the clipboard.. Like this...

```
set theMessage to "Whatever Text To Send"
set thePhoneNumber to "555-555-5555" -- Any Phone Number INCLUDE THE QUOTE MARKS
--               * Other Acceptable Phone Number Formats *
-- ("1(555)555-5555","(555)555-5555", "5555555555", "15555555555")

tell application "Messages" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    delay 1 -- May Need To Adjust
    click UI element "Compose" of splitter group 1 of window ¬
        "Messages" of application process "Messages"
    delay 1.5 -- May Need To Adjust
    set value of text field "To:" of scroll area 3 of splitter group 1 of window ¬
        "Messages" of application process "Messages" to thePhoneNumber
    keystroke return
    delay 1.5 -- May Need To Adjust
    set value of text area 1 of scroll area 4 of splitter group 1 of window ¬
        "Messages" of application process "Messages" to theMessage
    delay 2 -- May Need To Adjust
    keystroke return
end tell
```

Comment: I appreciate that, but these aren't phone numbers in the contacts app and unless they are, the direct method won't work. Backstory: dozens of people apply to a job, we text them a link to a questionnaire. Perhaps I can look into adding them as a record in Contacts.app first.

Comment: @Chuck , I just tested out the code in the first part of my answer, with three different phone numbers which are not in my contacts, and I had never messaged before, and never received a message from these numbers.  All three SMS messages were sent succesfully.  I'm not quite sure why you say "these aren't phone numbers in the contacts app and unless they are, the direct method won't work"  Did you actually test the code on your end? If so, what was the error message you received?

Comment: I'll try again, but when I try to directly send the message to a phone number *not* in my contacts, nothing happens. It's as if the code was not executed. I'll try under a different account.